# Проблема RewriteRule в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день имеется ссылка **gallery.php?gallery=test**
Хочу изменить на **gallery/test** но не получается а вот например на **gallery=test** изменяется

```
RewriteRule ^gallery=(.*)$ gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

Делаю так

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

не получается страница открывается без никаких css и js файлов и ссылки на странице не правильные экранировал слеш тоже не получается только вот не знаю правильно ли я это делаю

```
RewriteRule ^gallery\/(.*)$ gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Итак. Ваш второй вариант правильный

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

А левые JS и CSS у вас потому, что вы им задали относительные пути. То есть:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

Это **неправильно**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Это правильно.

Ищите различие и исправляйте **все** относительные пути на абсолютные. Тогда все будет работать. Не будет - дайте ссыль, ткну вас туда, где не исправили.

Comment: вообще интерестно получается...<br>
вопрос о mod rewrite а ответ о путях ^^

Comment: Я изменял, но не помогло, можно связаться по почте и сами, взглянуть? (r-unix@mail.ru)

Comment: <b>just no comments ^^</b>

Comment: Почта есть в профиле.

Comment: Спасибо Sh4dow решил проблему прописав
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="папка/css/style.css" />
и не удивляйтесь я всё таки не русский поэтому могу чтото не правильно спросить

Comment: @Royal, во-первых, вместо папки можно писать от корня сайта, смотрите: если мы в какой-то папке, (`http://site.ru/papka/`), то путь "css/style.css" указывает относительно этой папки, т.е. "`http://mysite.ru/papka/css/style.css`", где его, естественно, нет. При этом путь "/css/style.css" (слэш в начале) будет всегда указывать на "`http://mysite.ru/css/style.css`", где он есть.

Во-вторых, нажмите галку слева от вопроса =)

Comment: хватит тебе 2 плюсика :)

Comment: Sh4dow я тестировал на локалке полный путь был такой http://localhost/papka/index.php поэтому у меня не получалось

Answer (score 1):

Так:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

А стили и скрипты указывать относительно корня сайта, например:
    < link href="/css/style.css"...

Comment: нет не сработало

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

Comment: И только скажите, что не работает) проверил! )

Comment: Нет, не работает тоже.

Comment: <b>Ozim</b> разве не очевидно что афтар вообще 0, не может сформировать нормально вопрос и все что умеет это тупо пробывать то что ему подсунули под нос?

Comment: Нормально сформирован вопрос, я просто не могу понять, в чём проблема. Почему при изпользовании слешов выводит ошибку.

Comment: извиняюсь, перефразирую - автор некомпетентен...<br>
Так вас утсроит или всеравно какието вопросы еще есть?<br>
Вам 2 раза написали правила, если у вас что-то не работет то это роблема исключительно ваша и никто не обладает екстросенсорными способностями для того чтобы понять что не так у вас, я не умничал а написал(как и <b>Ozim</b>) нормальное правило, то что вы не смогли воспользоватся тупо готовым решением(подсуныутым прямо под ваш нос) и разобраться почему оно у вас не работает проблема исключительно ваша,   еще будут вопросы?

Comment: правило уменя работает и я не прошу готового решения просто хочу понять в чём проблема если тебе трудно помочь тоже можеш оставить свои ответы при себе

Comment: @Royal ну реально, у меня работает, у остальных работает, не работает только у вас.. это наталкивает на выводы :)
Скажите КАК именно у вас это не работает? что выдает браузер? где находится gallery.php и .htaccess относительно сайта? Больше инфы!

Comment: О_о я не являюсь топик стартером, а если бы являлся то вскрыл бы себе вены...

Comment: @AlexWindHope сорри я случайно ники попутал, сразу же исправил )

Comment: Спасибо, @Ozim, получилось, работал на локалке и прописал начиная с имени папки, сработало. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Не за что, принимайте ответ =)

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteRule ^galery\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ /galery.php?galery=$1 [L]
```

А так?

Comment: Нет, и так не работает.

Comment: У вас пути кривые, `Dem` правильно написал пути прописывать надо так чтобы рассположение страницы никак не влияло, т.е. от корня, т.е. сначала всегда и везде слеш... Ссылки нужно формировать также, htaccess тут не причем, если у вас работало до этого(а именно был редирект) - все остальные проблемы уже ищите у себя в путях ;) <br>
PS:Оно вам действительно надо? :)

Comment: Да я и пути менял  всёровну не помогло и rewriterule у меня работает

    RewriteRule ^gallery=(.*)$ gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]
это без проблем а так нет

    RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ gallery.php?gallery=$1 [L]

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы додумались изменить galery на gallery? ^^

Comment: @AlexWindHope 

> страница открывается без никаких css и js файлов

Вам вот это ни о чем не сказало?) Лол же

Comment: Вот именно, что лол, более того - еще и пытается оправдать свой faic palm...